# Android ListView alpha scroller for quickly scrolling long list

Tags: android, listview, scroll

The Contacts app shows a button on the side of the screen that acts as a little thumb to allow you to quickly scroll the big list. I have a very long list that would benefit from this navigation behavior, but can't find any documentation as to how to enable it.

Is it a behavior that's built into the SDK, or must I write it myself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is included in the sdk.  See here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:fastScrollEnabled

just set this property.  If you want to further enhance this like the contacts that shows the letters for the section you are in you can use this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't look up the hierarchy to find that, and my searches were fruitless. Thank you!

Comment: Is there something else required.  I set my ListView to fastScrollEnabled = true and I don't see a difference.

Comment: @Andrew
1) Look at http://rognotes.appspot.com/2012/07/Implementing-a-ListView-with-AlphabetIndexer-and-CursorAdapter-on-Android
2) Also Override swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) to reset mAlphabetIndexer

  //Sets a new cursor as the data set and resets the cache of indices.
  mAlphabetIndexer.setCursor(newCursor);